# JavaScript - Bootstrap Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin: [Plugin Link](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

I am trying to validate, if at least one checkbox out of a checkbox group has been selected. The plugin doesn't support such a functionality. Therefore i googled, and found this, by the plugin author himself: [Discussion Link](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/96) and a working implementation here: [Example](http://jsbin.com/xosabirowu/1/edit?html,js,output)

I tried implementing it and failed. This is what i have so far:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">

                <?php
                // Input form for choosing complaints
                foreach (Complaints::getComplaints() as $complaint) {
                    ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="complaints[]" data-chkgrp="complaints[]"
                                       data-error="Try selecting at least one...">
                                <?= Helper::sanitize($complaint->getName()) ?>
                            </label>

                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                }
                ?>

            </div>
```

Plus this is the copied JS Function, that should do the magic...:

```
<script>
$('[data-toggle="validator"]').validator({
    custom: {
        chkgrp: function ($el) {
            console.log("Some debug output, if it is triggered at all" + $el);
            var name = $el.data("chkgrp");
            var $checkboxes = $el.closest("form").find('input[name="' + name + '"]');

            return $checkboxes.is(":checked");
        }
    },
    errors: {
        chkgrp: "Choose atleast one!"
    }
}).on("change.bs.validator", "[data-chkgrp]", function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    console.log("Does is even work? " + $el);
    var name = $el.data("chkgrp");
    var $checkboxes = $el.closest("form").find('input[name="' + name + '"]');

    $checkboxes.not(":checked").trigger("input");
});
```

So yeeh. Nothing happens, if i try to run this. None of my debug output is printed in the console. Nothing. The form itself also consists out of some password fields and text fields, the checkbox group - generated in the foreach loop - is just one part of it. The validator works for the text and password fields, but does exactly nothing for the checkbox group. Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: can you provide the html after php processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to make it neat.
please checkout the solution:

Reference: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

```js
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  var validate = false;
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index,e){
    
    if($(e).is(':checked'))
      validate = true;
  });
  
  if(validate){
    //valid
    $('.with-errors').html(' ');
  } else {
    $('.with-errors').html('not valid');

  }
  
  //if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  //} else {
    // everything looks good!
  //}
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>





<form  role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="form" action="" method="POST">
<div class="col-lg-9">


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="complaints[]" data-chkgrp="complaints[]" data-error="Try selecting at least one...">
        Teste1
      </label>
    
      <div class="help-block  "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="complaints[]" data-chkgrp="complaints[]" data-error="Try selecting at least one...">
        Teste2
      </label>
    
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="complaints[]" data-chkgrp="complaints[]" data-error="Try selecting at least one...">
        Teste3
      </label>
    
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

</div>
  <button type="submit" >Validade</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the code to the following:

if(validate){
                $(".checkbox .with-errors").html("");
                $("#registerForm").find(":submit").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $(".checkbox .with-errors").html("Select at least one").css("color", "rgb(169, 68, 66)");
                $("#registerForm").find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
            }